# cdc_acm initialization takes a long time

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, tty, cdc

I'm having an USB device, which is not a modem, that gets recognized as a ttyACM under Linux. I can open this path for read/write operations with standard system calls. The problem I have seen is that in the first 20 seconds after plug-in, some USB packets are lost, and this happens with great probability.

I recompiled the cdc_acm driver and enabled DEBUG and VERBOSE_DEBUG. Since the output is too long, I'm pasting it [here](http://pastebin.com/pFVK4Gvq). I'm seeing the sequence  `acm_tty_install`, `acm_tty_open` repeated twice, under no apparent reason. Also, there are many `acm_softint` calls which take somewhere around 3 seconds to "finish", based on dmesg timestamps.

Appreciate if you have some clues on what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the **modemmanager** daemon triggers upon plug-in and start sending AT commands to my device, repeating it twice, probably because it doesn't get any response. A simple `stop modemmanager` does the trick.